# Preference key always return null

Tags: android

I have a Preference Screen in my android app which contains a call to the system settings via an inner Preference and some Switches options as below:

```
<PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/preferences_activity_supervisor_settings_title">

    <Preference
        android:key="@+id/instrument_preference"
        android:title="@string/instrument_settings"
        android:summary="@string/instrument_settings">

    </Preference>

    <com.CustomSwitchPreference
        android:key="@string/prefs_super_autosend_key"
        android:title="@string/prefs_super_autosend_title"
        android:summary="@string/prefs_super_autosend_summary"
        android:defaultValue="false"/>
```

...
...

My class extends PreferenceFragment and I added the resources using addPreferencesFromResource(). It works without problems.

However, the method onPreferenceTreeClick(), when I click in the Fragment **(keyID = instrument_preference)** the preferences always brings me key as **NULL**. All other options in the preference fragment I can read the key.

The question is why and how I detect the user clicked in the first element of my preference list ?

Answer (score 2):

First remove + from @+id, because every time it create a new key due to @+id, thats why you get null.

And to detect SharedPreference is changed use this simple code:

```
public class MyPreferences extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                 addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.fw_preferences); //deprecated
                 PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
               // handle the preference change here
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing @+id before the preference key name

It should be like

```
 <Preference
    android:key="instrument_preference" 
    android:title="@string/instrument_settings"
    android:summary="@string/instrument_settings">

</Preference>
```